# Django compare strings in template (for loop) and replace output

Tags: django, django-templates

There is a forloop in a template file in django

```
{% for tag in tags_list %}
        {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

The output is all the contents in tags_list like the example below

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I tried to replace number 3 with the string "Not available" like below

```
{% for tag in tags_list %}
    {% if 3 == tag %}
      {% tag = "Not available" %}
      {{ tag }}
    {% else %}
      {{ tag }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it does not work.
There are two problems:

> 1- {% if 3 == tag %} cannot compare.
>
> 2- {% tag == "Not available" %} cannot change the value of the
>   variable.

What is wrong with these codes?

Comment: Is `tags_list` a list of `int` or is it a list of `str`?

Comment: Rather than changing the value of the variable, why not do `{% if tag == 3 %}Not available{% else %}...{% endif %}`?

Answer (score 0):

If your tag list is string then

```
{% if '3' == tag %}
     Not available # your msg
{%else%}
      {{tag}} 
{%endif%}
```

You can assign anything in your views and display in your template.